# DateTime with format 'yyyy-MM-dd' not working in SQL Query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, datetime

i am facing a problem in the sql date conversion query

```
Declare @time datetime
set @time = '2014-08-02'
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @time, 111) 'Date Part Only'
```

The Above Query give me output as '2014/08/02'

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), '2014-08-02', 111) 'Date Part Only'
```

But if i give directly above query does not give me '2014/08/02' but instead it gives me '2014-08-02'

Why cant i give the date direcly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ans is string vs datetime. So you get diff result.

For same result.

```
Declare @time datetime
set @time = '2014-08-02'

print  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @time, 111) --- 'Date Part Only'
print  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), convert (datetime,'2014-08-02'), 111) ---'Date Part Only'
```

Answer (score 2):

`'2014-08-02'` is a string, and `@time` is a datetime.  That's why you are seeing different behavior.  If you want to force it to be a datetime, `CONVERT` it to datetime first.  There are no datetime literals, so you have to do some explicit conversion or variable declaration.